# Is it possible to insert a list of widgets without having to define a method or property?

Tags: flutter, dart

The following is a pseudo code that I want to have.

```
void main() => runApp(
      Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: [Text('Start'),...[1,2,3].forEach((element) {Text('$element')}), Text('Finish')],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Here I want to insert a list of `Text` without having to write a method or a property. Is it possible in Dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `map` method from `Iterable` in conjunction with the spread operator you already have.

```dart
[Text('Start'),...[1,2,3].map((element) {return Text('$element');}), Text('Finish')]
```

Comment: @NotAZoomedImage What do you mean `range`-like? Maybe [`List.generate`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/List/List.generate.html) will help you.

Comment: Actually what I was looking for is `[...List.generate(100, (i) => Text('$i')),]` rather than `map`. :-)